# How I can obtain twitter access token secret using access token on server side?

Tags: .net, twitter, tweetsharp

I have only access token on server side. I try to use TweetSharp for abtaining user_id:

```
var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
TwitterUser user = service.VerifyCredentials();
var id = user.Id;
```

But I have no _accessTokenSecret, only _accessToken. Is there another way to obtain user_id?

Comment: The twitter's token is always in duo with a token secret. Where is your token secret, how do you fetch your tokens ? Without both of them you cannot use the api.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I recieved accessToken from iOS client which stores only accessTokenSecret. But we found such decision on client side https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth.